# How to 'sneak' interface behind 3rd party objects

Tags: c#, interface, .net-4.5

I am working with `C#`, `.NET 4.5`.
I have 2 objects (actually more but for sake of simplicity lets stick with two) that are separate entities and all come from 3rd party libraries, however they do have few common properties.

I want to do an abstract mechanism that would work with these properties. If these objects would be mine I could do it easily by adding interface

```
class Foo : IFooBar
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IFooBar
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

interface IFooBar
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IFooBar ProcessedFoobars(IFooBar fooBar)
    {
    ...(do things to A and B)
    }
}
```

However since they come from 3rd party I have no (don't know a) way of putting them behind interface.

Options I see ATM:

1. Convert `Foo` and `Bar` to `MyFoo` and `MyBar` that are my internal objects put `MyFoo` and `MyBar` behind interface and handle them this way
2. Use a method that accepts only properties as inputs.

   ```
   Tuple<string, string> DoThings(string A, string B)
   {
   ...(do things to A and B)
   }
   ```

This will involve lots of mapping from each flavour of 3rd party object.

3. At this point I am leaning to using reflection.

   ```
   public T FooBarProcessor<T>(T fooBar)
   {
       var type = typeof (T);
       var propertyA = type.GetProperty("A");
       var propertyB = type.GetProperty("B");
       var a = propertyA.GetValue(fooBar, null);
       var b = propertyB.GetValue(fooBar, null);
       ... (do things to A and B)
       propertyA.SetValue(fooBar, a);
       propertyB.SetValue(fooBar, b);
       return fooBar;
   }
   ```

**Is there a way to 'sneak' interface behind 3rd party objects (or some other workaround) that would allow me to make multiple objects seem as if they are behind interface, so I could deal with them all in same way.**

<s>What gives me hope that this could be done - there's [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/purchase) that does allows to do 'Aspect Inheritance' (haven't tried it myself, so it might be something different) in pay'd version and if they do this somehow - then this can be done.</s>

Comment: PostSharp modifies and rebuilds the assemblies from the ground up.

You have no option but to wrap the 3rd party objects inside objects of your own where you can add your interfaces.

Comment: PostSharp 'patches' the IL - nothing you want to do...

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying the assemblies. You could opt for creating your own proxy classes (with your generic interface) which call the 3rd party classes.

Comment: @LIUFA Well... there is always `dynamic`, which will allow you to duck-type against the types, but that moves all problems (such as missing properties or different types) to the runtime and involves the DLR in your application, which you may or may not want to invoke for such a trivial case. I would personally either wrap the types (adapter answer) or have the methods take properties directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is [adapter pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter).

You can create classes that implements your interface and use Foo & Bar in the background:

```
interface IFooBar
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
}

class FooAdapter : IFooBar
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public FooAdapter(Foo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public string A
    {
        get { return _foo.A; }
        set { _foo.A = value; }
    }

    public string B
    {
        get { return _foo.B; }
        set { _foo.B = value; }
    }
}


class BarAdapter : IFooBar
{
    private readonly Bar _bar;

    public BarAdapter(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public string A
    {
        get { return _bar.A; }
        set { _bar.A = value; }
    }

    public string B
    {
        get { return _bar.B; }
        set { _bar.B = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This *THE* 'most correct answer' (if time is not an issue), however in my case fast and dirty solution is more appropriate. Thanks Ufuk.

Comment: @LIUFA For the benefit of the community, you should really mark the best solution and use the one you prefer.

Comment: @LIUFA Big love from me to you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a correct or most common solution you should follow [Ufuk´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979747/83039).

My solution provides a faster way to solve the problem, but in case of a longterm use this is not recommended.

When I understand your problem correct, you could try to use a method that accepts a dynamic object as parameter.

```
public static void ChangeCommonProperties(dynamic thirdPartyObject){
  thirdPartyObject.A = "Hello";
  thirdPartyObject.B = "World";
}

ChangeCommonProperties(new Foo());
ChangeCommonProperties(new Bar());
```

As long as the object passed in has the properties and the property type is correct, this works without problems. Otherwise you get a `RuntimeBinderException` with details what went wrong.

Comment: `dynamic` should not be used as substitute for proper design. It is intended for use with dynamically typed language interop, not for OO workarounds.

Comment: @Gusdor. Sure Ufuk answer is the better and right way, but you need to implement many wrapper classes to handle the case and when many types are involved then this could be complex

Comment: `dynamic` is a valid approach to the problem depending on other factors, but you may wish to highlight the pitfalls and alternatives in your answer. Sometimes, and mostly because of third party issues, perceived "evils" become necessary.

Comment: This would be great, but they have to come out as `Foo` and `Bar` out of mechanism, (`public static dynamic ChangeCommonProperties(dynamic thirdPartyObject)`) still a very nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: It works! Sir you are a saviour .        `public void ProcessFooBars()
        {
          var x = (Foo)ChangeCommonProperties(new Foo());
          var y = (Bar)ChangeCommonProperties(new Bar());
        }` and then `        public T ProcessFooBars<T>(dynamic anything)
        {
            return (T) ChangeCommonProperties(anything);
        }`

Comment: In the event of a breaking change, this solution will only fail at run time. You will only find it if you have test coverage. An adapter solution will fail at compile time. The "complex" way pays for itself in the long term. That is the difference between the correct solution and a hack.

Comment: @Gusdor Its not a hack its another solution to the problem.

Comment: @Gusdor we are talking about ~50 3rd party classes and 28 properties each :) usage is to set default values on them. It would take me couple of days to write the wrappers, now I will be finished in couple an hour. If I had 3 classes I would do wrappers, but not today :)

Comment: @LIUFA lets hope it doesn't blow up when you upgrade to the next library version!

Comment: @LIUFA: Given that each of the ~50 classes has the same (read: same name, same type) properties, you'd only have to write *one* wrapper with the 28 properties (and if the code for each property is really as simple as shown above, you can generate that code in a loop), copy and paste it ~50 times and replace the class name three times (wrapper name, wrapper ctor parameter, and wrapper private field to the wrapped instance).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified solution I ended up using, thanks to @Jehof.

```
public T ProcessFooBars<T>(dynamic anything) 
{ 
    return (T) ChangeCommonProperties(anything); 
}

public dynamic ChangeCommonProperties(dynamic thirdPartyObject)
{
    thirdPartyObject.A = "Hello";
    thirdPartyObject.B = "World";
}
```

Hope this saves you some time.